# How to load a modification using insertBefore () in a ChMethod with Javassist?

Tags: java, javassist

I'm trying to insert a code fragment at the beggining of the body of a method from a class originating from a jar from another project. 
In this current project, I'm using tha javassist library, with it I am able to find and manipulate the class and the method that I want to modify, since I have added the jar of this old project as library in this current one. Here is the code where I can do this:

```
try {
    ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass vendaControllerCt = classPool.getCtClass("com.t2tierp.pafecf.controller.VendaController");
    CtMethod[] methods = vendaControllerCt.getMethods();
    for(CtMethod method : methods){
        if(method.getName().equals("insereVendaCabecalhoTrocaDevolucao")){
            method.insertBefore("{pVendaCabecalho.setCupomSat(java.lang.Boolean.FALSE);");
        }
    }
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (CannotCompileException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this section, as soon as I find the method that I want to modify, named `insereVendaCabecalhoTrocaDevolucao`, I insert the new line to be ajusted using the library method `insertBefore()`. But when I am executing the project and I call the method that I modificated, the adjustment is not loaded, and the original method is loaded without my adjustments.

Using the `InstructionPrint.print(),` I could verify that the change is apparently being made, but not loaded when I call the method.

What is missing for my modification to be called when executing the method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem setting the bytecode class with the changes. 
Here is the code where with the solution:

```
if(method.getName().equals("insereVendaCabecalhoTrocaDevolucao")){
    method.insertBefore("{pVendaCabecalho.setCupomSat(java.lang.Boolean.FALSE);}");
    byteCode = vendaControllerCt.toBytecode();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `writeFile` on your CtClass-object to save the changes in your file.